# How to 301 redirect only one domain on server with multiple domains

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, redirect

I'm attempting to redirect a site of mine to another site, but there are other domains in the same folder.

How do I only redirect one specific domain to another domain?
Would this work

> RewriteRule http://oldomain.com/(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/ [L,R=301]

Answer (score 1):

No, you must use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,NE,L]
```

Or if you don't ask for the same file/directory in newdomain.com:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://newdomain.com/ [R=301,L]
```